# escaping complicated string in javascript

Tags: javascript, escaping

I have an input, in which user can type any character he/she wants.

I want to escape this characters using Javascript. This appears to be problematic in some cases. Take this string for example;

```
0,;.:-_()!"#$%&'()*?/
```

how would you escape this?

I used

```
escape(), and encodeURIComponent()
```

but I am having some issues with `'` and `"` characters. note that it is the user that chooses types in this string.

Comment: for what purpose do you need an escaped string?

Comment: You can use replace:

str.replace(/'/g, "\\'");

Comment: I am going to perform hash on it. but really, you cannot do anything withou escaping, because javascript interprets " as end of the string

Comment: Escape it for consumption by what?

Comment: If the string comes from an input, `"` will not be interpreted as the end of the string, all you have to do to send it, is put it through `encodeURIComponent` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `encodeURIComponent`, `escape` is deprecated

```js
function encodeInput() {
  var encoded = encodeURIComponent(document.querySelector('#input').innerHTML);
  document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML = encoded;
}
```

```html
<div id="input">
  0,;.:-_()!"#$%&'()*?/
</div>
<div id="output">
</div>
<button onclick="encodeInput()">
  Encode Input
</button>
```

jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/kadqp4aq/